# To be logged in or not to be logged in that is the question

Tags: bug, login

I suddenly feel like [Schrödinger's cat](http://xn--schrdinger's%20cat-g3b/) as I am both logged in and not logged in!

Please can someone open my box and tell what is going on?

[image]

And if I click "log in"

[image]

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 59.0.2

Comment: No! You did not hand draw the boxes!

Comment: @Pheo I'm a senior citizen. My hand shakes too much to draw anything sensible with my trackerball :)

Comment: First thing one must do before reporting a bug in SE is disable all the fancy userscripts/plugins people made over the years to "improve" stuff.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by others, this strange login box is caused by [SOX](https://github.com/soscripted/sox) and appears to be a regression error.

I've made a [new bug report](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/317).

Comment: Uh... Who pointed that out?

Comment: @Pheo Other moderators in the mod private room :)

Comment: sorry... I'll get this fixed ASAP